# jQuery: Is the jquery alphanumeric plugin still supported?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Just wondering if this plugin is still supported, cant find any contact details to report a bug.

There is also no license info, can I assume I can change it and use it?

http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a [replacement to the jQuery alphanumeric plugin](http://treyhunner.com/2010/10/replacement-for-jquery-alphanumeric-plugin/) that *is* still supported and resolves a few issues that I had with the original plugin.  The plugin codebase and issue tracker can be found on Github: https://github.com/treyhunner/jquery-formrestrict

Comment: I read your answer as I was in an old project trying to add support for copying and pasting to the old alphanumeric plugin I'd downloaded, and you have it all working! Great work!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't jQuery itself released under the GPL / MIT License? If I remember correctly, that allows you to modify any source code, modifications, or extensions as you see fit assuming you also apply the GPL / MIT license to your released work.

Comment: If it doesnt specifically have a license or contacts details can I just incorporate the code into my own code without credit?

Comment: was hoping to get more of an answer about continued support, but will just change it myself...